# ojdbc8 DB_URL for fail over

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using ojdbc8 driver which gets a connection string format as the following:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP"
```

however, I'd like to use a fail over connection string with the following format:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = site1)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = site2)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
  )
  (FAILOVER=ON)
  (FAILOVER_MODE=
    (TYPE=SELECT)
    (METHOD=BASIC)
    (RETRIES=20)
    (DELAY=3)
  )
  (LOAD_BALANCE = OFF)
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
  )
)"
```

. 
when I'm using the fail over format I get an error message:
"Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid" "

the none fail over connection string which is working:

```
String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

***any suggestions on how solving it ? ***

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with just the JDBC connection URL, you will require at least The Universal Connection Pool (UCP) to be enabled in the client.

You should start by reading the [10.1.1 Configuring Fast Connection Failover for JDBC Clients](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm#HABPT5381) chapter in the documentation. Make sure to read the documentation specific to your database version because JDBC driver might have different features e.g. odjcb6 in 11g vs ojdbc8 in 12c.